# Issue in passing data into fragments inside pager adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Here is my view pager adapter to load fragments. Inside the getItem() method, I am trying to insert the values dynamically using the index passed to that function. I have all the data inside productData. But it always fetches the value of

```
 productData.get(0).get("name")
```

into all the fragments. The index value is correctly being passed into fragments. I verified it. And also the data inside the productData is also correct. Where is the issue here?

```
  public class ProductViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ProductViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {            
        Fragment fragment = new ProductViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("number", i + 1);
        args.putString("name", productData.get(i).get("name"));
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return "test1";
            case 1: return "2";
            case 2: return "3";
            case 3: return "4";
        }
        return null;
    }     

 }
```

Comment: I would try outputting the two values `i+1` and `productData.get(i).get("name")` to the log, inside your `getItem()` method, just to check one more time that you are putting the correct values into the bundle.

Comment: Yes. I tried it. The number counter is increasing correctly as I swipe to next fragments. But the name value is still stays with the first item in all the fragments.

Comment: Then I doubt that the data in `productData` is correct. Can you show your code to create `productData`?

Comment: I understand what is the mistake here. The productData contains only the last index data. But am I storing data wrongly in the below function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only have a single `HashMap`. Even though you keep changing the data inside the `HashMap`, the list `productItems` just contains 10 references to the single `HashMap`. So in the end, it will contain 10 copies of the final set of data.

What you want to do is create a new `HashMap` for each loop iteration. Here's the modified code:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getData(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asynctask, String query) throws URISyntaxException
{
    api_url += query;
    //  Log.v("API url",api_url);
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(api_url); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PRODUCT);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);           
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(KEY_PROD_NAME, e.getAttribute(KEY_PROD_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_ID, e.getAttribute(KEY_MER_ID));
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, e.getAttribute(KEY_MER_PRICE));      
        Log.v("fsd:",e.getAttribute(KEY_PROD_NAME));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        productItems.add(map);      
    }       
    return productItems;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is that,

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getData(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asynctask, String query) throws URISyntaxException
{   
        api_url += query;
        //  Log.v("API url",api_url);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(api_url); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PRODUCT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);           
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_PROD_NAME, e.getAttribute(KEY_PROD_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_ID, e.getAttribute(KEY_MER_ID));
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, e.getAttribute(KEY_MER_PRICE));      
        Log.v("fsd:",e.getAttribute(KEY_PROD_NAME));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        productItems.add(map);      
    }       
    return productItems;    
}
```